# $X$ a r.v. verifying $P(X=x)=0$&$F_X$ its repartition fct. Prove that $F_X(X)$ follows an uniform distribution law $]0;1[$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

#### Question:

Let $X$ a r.v. verifying $P(X=x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F_X$ its repartition function. Prove that $F_X(X)$ follows an uniform distribution law $]0;1[$.

#### Answer:

1- We write $0 \leq F_X(x)=P(X < x ) \leq 1$ which is a continuous and a not - decreasing function.
*$F_X(x)=P(X < x )$ is continuous*
First note that by definition $ P(a < x<b) = F_X(b) -F_X(a) , \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. This mean that for all sequence $a_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} a $ we will have (wlog $a_n > a,  \forall n $) that: $\left \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < a_n  \right \}  \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} \varnothing \Rightarrow P(a < x< a_n) = F_X(a_n)-F_X(a) \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} P(\varnothing)= 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} (F_X(a_n)-F_X(a)) = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} F_X(a_n) = F_X(a) $
More over $ \forall t \in ]0;1[ , \exists  x \in \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $ t = F_X(x) $. Now via Heine theorem we can conclude that $F_X(x)$ is continuous.
*$F_X(x)=P(X < x )$ is a not - decreasing function*
Trivial.

2- We then write $\forall t \in ]0;1[, F_X^{-1}(t) = Sup \left \{ x  \in \mathbb{R} : F_X(x) = t\right \} $. We have too by definition of the inverse function that $F_X(F^{-1}_X(t))=t$
This supremum exists because for every $0<t<1$ the set $\left \{ x  \in \mathbb{R} : F_X(x) = t\right \}$ is bounded from above and no empty.
*The set is bounded from above*
Indeed if the set was not bounded from above it will mean $ \exists 0<t'<1 $ s.t. $\left \{ x  \in \mathbb{R} : F_X(x) = t' \right \} = ]- \infty ; + \infty[$ but by hypothesis the only $t'$ that can verify this are the one verifying $ t \geq 1$ and this is not possible.
*The set is no empty*
Very similar to the prove above but here the $t'$ that will verify the emptynes of the set will be $t' < 0 $.

3- Using hte fact that $F_X$ is a  no-decreasing function $F_X(x) \leq t \Rightarrow x \leq F^{-1}_X(t) $.
Hence $P( F_X(X) \leq t) = P(X \leq F^{-1}_X(t) ) = P(X < F^{-1}_X(t) ) = F_X(F^{-1}_X(t))=t , \forall 0<t<1$.
Hence $F_X(X)$ follow an uniform law.

Is it correct?
I have mostly a question in my part "1-" when I prove the continuity of the function $F_X(x)$ and in part "2-" when I prove that the set is bonded from above?
More generally is there is a lake of justification in my global reasoning?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: En anglais, fonction de répartition --> cumulative distribution function

Comment: @JoseAvilez thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my answer is correct.

More precision concerning the $P( F_X(X) \leq t) = P(X \leq F^{-1}_X(t) )$ cames from the fact that the inequality $X \leq F^{-1}_X(t)$ is equivalent to the inequation $F_X(X) \leq t$ hence we apply the increasing function $F_X(.)$ on both side. (I hope this explanation is correct).